# How to resolve GTID difference between Master and Slave servers in MariaDB replication using MaxScale?

Tags: mariadb, master-slave-replication, gtid, maxscale

I wrote accidently directly on the Slave DB, and therefore the data is not in sync anymore.

When I check MaxScale status, all servers are running, but the Slaves are not detected as "Slave" and there is a difference in GTID.

[image]

Does anyone know how to put them back in sync?

I've already searched for information into the documentation of MaxScale, but I could not find this specific usecase there: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-2302-automatic-failover-with-mariadb-monitor/

Comment: Links are not on. Please  post the question here. You need to put in some effort if you want people to spend their time helping you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution in this article: https://www.redips.net/mysql/replication-slave-relay-log-corrupted/

I had to detect the last bin log from the Master node, and to execute the following commands on both slave nodes:

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G;
STOP SLAVE;
RESET SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO master_log_file='nodex-bin.XXX(last binlog by date)',
 master_log_pos=4; # 4 for the beginning of the log file
START SLAVE;
```

Comment: sounds like [sync_binlog=1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-and-binary-log-system-variables/#sync_binlog) is needed for prevention.